How can I alter truncated images so that they won't trigger a "cannot identify image file" error withPIL?
For some PNG images (all have sizes 50KB and below), this script fails:
img = Image.open('path_to_img')
img

with the error
UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file
I have looked up similar issues, and successfully ran the script above and displayed the resulting image, with the addition of the line
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

However, these images will be used by a third-party function containing the original script, which I cannot alter. The third-party function must also use all the images in the dataset. Therefore my only option is to ensure that the images are not truncated and/or do not trigger an UnidentifiedImageError. How can I efficiently convert these images to a usable format?

You'd need to share one or two images that generate that error. You'll probably need to use Dropbox or Google Drive or some service that doesn't alter/restrict images.

I'm not really sure what you are asking. Do you want to know how to identify which images are truncated? If you can load the images adequately with LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True why don't you just do that for all the images and resave them before calling the unalterable third party function? I'm confused as to the real issue. Why are your images truncated?
